# Information about XML 2.0

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-1.1

I need to build an XML document with XML version 2.0.

I specify `<?xml version="2.0"?>`. But what else needs to be different?
Can anyone please explain the basic difference between XML 1.1 and XML 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time (2015), there is no XML 2.0, nor is there any work presently underway to define a version 2.0.   There is an [XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) and an [XML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/) currently.   The motivation for XML 1.1 is described in the [Rationale and list of changes for XML 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-xml11) section of the W3C XML 1.1 Recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @kjhughes. That's what I was assuming.